# How to write multiple if statement R

Tags: r, if-statement, raster, r-raster, rgdal

I am manipulating raster data in R with the `rgdal` and `raster` packages. I want to get rid of all infinite, no values, negative values and replace them with zero:

```
NoNA <- function (x) { 
    x[is.infinite(x) | is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.null(x) | is.na(x < 0)] <- 0
}
ndii_noNA <- calc(ndii, NoNA)
```

Then the `ndii_noNA` have only a value of 0. I tried if else statement but it raises an error in

```
.calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply).
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: you need `{x[stuff] <- 0; x}` you're currently returning the assigned values, not the object `x`

Comment: you need to return the x vector after the manipulation.

Comment: and you could `x <- c(1, NA, NaN, -2, 0, 1); x[!is.finite(x) | x < 0] <- 0; x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, but have made two errors:

1. You need to use `which()` in the index of `x`, rather than just the truth statement. Otherwise, you will index either `x[TRUE]` or `x[FALSE]`, which is not what you want. `which()` will return the indices of all "bad" elements in your vector.
2. When you make the assignment with `<-`, the local copy of `x` will be changed, not the one that was passed. If you want to change `x` in place, you need to use `<<-`. That said, you would be wise to stick to R's functional paradigm, in which you would make the change to the local copy, then return it with `return(x)`, rather than change in place.

Here is the function you want:

```
# The "change in place" method (may be considered bad style)
NoNA <- function(x) {
  x[which(is.infinite(x) | is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.null(x) | is.na(x < 0))] <<- 0
}
# The functional way (recommended)
NoNA <- function(x) {
  x[which(is.infinite(x) | is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.null(x) | is.na(x < 0))] <- 0
  return(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: ifelse() is cleaner but the @cgmil's answer is indeed faster.

```
    x = rep(c(Inf, -Inf, NULL, NaN, NA, 1), 250e3)

    no_na = function(x){

      ifelse(
        is.infinite(x) | is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.null(x) | is.na(x < 0), 0, x
      )

    }


NoNA <- function(x) {
  x[which(is.infinite(x) | is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.null(x) | is.na(x < 0))] <- 0
  return(x)
}

microbenchmark(
  no_na(x), NoNA(x),
  times = 50
)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# no_na(x) 380.9375 399.7520 416.7729 424.5490 429.6005 451.0534    50
# NoNA(x) 242.8555 249.0034 255.8857 251.3694 254.8176 285.1451    50
```